# jQuery Style Template

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, dreamweaver

Have you worked in WPF? If yes you might have kown about the templates you can apply using the data provided.

I want to do same in jQuery; I have

- Image
- Image description
- Image price and others

I want to create a template that gives like the following

[image: Template]

So If I create this Template I should be able to do this

[image: Template Applied]

I need a tutorial or hint to do this.

I'm using Dreamweaver for developing the web site

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV But Sir/Ma'am I'm just asking an algorithm or method to this; like "use this, you will get want you want" which comes under the category of "a specific problem" and "software algorithm" I suppose and in which I'm asking. I'm not asking a whole book to be written down here, please.

Comment: Additionally I know jQuery quite well. All I need is a tip to the door :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Answer.

All I need to do is create the template; the above shown thing in PHP i.e

[image: Template]

Now apply the Template by making an Ajax Query to the PHP file through jQuery with the appropriate data to be shown.

And I have successfully done this.

Thanks to Head First in AJAX and jQuery.

I'm always happy to find answers for my question. And thanks for the efforts.

Comment: There's no reason to do it in PHP if you don't have to... but that's your call.

Answer (score 1):

I can't claim ownership for the concept, but here is my adaptation of Rick Strahl's work on top of John Resig's (all hail Resig) microtemplating engine.

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Oct/13/Client-Templating-with-jQuery

I really like's Rick's additions to this concept, which is why I include them here.  I use my own derivation of these concepts in my own standardized libraries, and they really work well, and are drop-dead simple to implement.

There was a templating engine slated to go directly into jQuery... but it was canned.  And although it is still available as a plug-in, I was never a fan of that implementation, so I can't really recommend it.